# Java script doesn't want to convert CSS to a number

Tags: javascript, css

The code is the following:

```
var b = Number(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left); //0
var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left, 10); //NaN
var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left); //NaN
```

Why cant I get the numeric value of the position of `someElement`?

Comment: What does console.log(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left) output?

Comment: You cant convert 50px to a integer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getComputedStyle`:

```
//This only works if you set the value in "style"
parseInt(document.getElementById('someElement').style.left, 10);

//If the value was set in a class declaration, use this:
parseInt(
    getComputedStyle(
        document.getElementById('someElement')
    ).getPropertyValue( "left" ),
    10
);
```

However, if the value is "auto", then this won't work, so you need to check for that first.

Comment: @user2864740 Well, then my second piece is the answer: `getComputedStyle`

Answer (score -1):

can you use `offsetLeft` function

```
var left = document.getElementById('someElement').offsetLeft;
```

Comment: `offsetLeft` is not the same thing as the `left` style. Margins are included and `float: right; left: 0px` would give a different `offsetLeft` than a non-floated element.

Comment: Altought the difference from what i wanted, that it what gets my work done - Thanks!

Comment: @Toffer use `getComputedStyle` as I show in my answer.